# Nivo Slider - Use mouseenter to change image

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, nivo-slider

I'm trying to make nivo slider images change when the mouse rolls over menu items. I've created a new class "nivoLink", and I can make the slides change using 'click'. This code works perfectly:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
jQuery('.nivoLink').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var targetImage = jQuery(this).attr('rel')-1;
var slideNo=jQuery('.nivoSlider').data('nivo:vars').currentSlide; 
if(targetImage!=slideNo) jQuery('.nivo-control').eq(targetImage).trigger('click');
});
});
```

I just can't make it work with 'mouseenter' I've been through many variations, but this is the most recent code version I'm trying without success.

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
jQuery('.nivoLink').mouseenter(function() {
var targetImage=jQuery(this).attr('rel')-1;
var slideNo=jQuery('.nivoSlider').data('nivo:vars').currentSlide; 
if(targetImage!=slideNo) jQuery('.nivo-control').eq(targetImage).trigger('mouseenter');
});
});
```

Site is underconstruction at visitcvfarm.com Hopefully I'm just missing something obvious since I'm pretty new to JQuery. Worth mentioning - this is the regular version of nivo installed on a Wordpress site - not the Wordpress plugin. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you make a small change to jquery.nivo.slider.js you can make this happen.
By adding below code you create an extra function which handles 'mouseenter' events on li items in an ul with the class 'nivoMenuControl'.

```
// jquery.nivo.slider.js
// ~line 18
var vars = {
    currentSlide: 0,
    currentImage: '',
    totalSlides: 0,
    index: 0,        // this one
    oldIndex: 0,     // this one
    running: false,
    paused: false,
    stop: false,
};

// ~line 220 right after 'For pauseOnHover setting'
// MouseEnter change slide
if(settings.mouseEnterControl){
    if($('body').find('.nivoMenuControl')) {
        $('.nivoMenuControl').children('li').mouseenter(function(){
            if(!vars.running){
                oldIndex = index;
                index = $(this).index();
            }               
            if(!vars.running && (index != oldIndex)){
                clearInterval(timer);
                timer = '';
                sliderImg.attr('src', vars.currentImage.attr('src'));
                vars.currentSlide = index;
                nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'control');
            }
        });
    }
}

// bottom of file
// Default settings
$.fn.nivoSlider.defaults = {
    effect: 'random',
    slices: 15,
    boxCols: 8,
    boxRows: 4,
    animSpeed: 500,
    pauseTime: 3000,
    startSlide: 0,
    directionNav: true,
    controlNav: true,
    controlNavThumbs: false,
    mouseEnterControl: false,       // This One
    pauseOnHover: true,
    manualAdvance: false,
    prevText: 'Prev',
    nextText: 'Next',
    randomStart: false,
    beforeChange: function(){},
    afterChange: function(){},
    slideshowEnd: function(){},
    lastSlide: function(){},
    afterLoad: function(){}
};
```

And then in the HTML you could do it like this:

```
<div id="menuSlider" class="nivoSlider">
    <img src="img/up.jpg" alt="" data-thumb="img/thumb_up.png" />
    <img src="img/walle.jpg" alt="" data-thumb="img/thumb_walle.png" />
    <img src="img/nemo.jpg" alt="" data-thumb="img/thumb_nemo.png" />
</div>
<ul class="nivoMenuControl">
    <li><a href="#">Slide01</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Slide02</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Slide03</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the jQuery would need these settings:

```
$('#menuSlider').nivoSlider({
    directionNav: false,
    controlNav: false,
    manualAdvance: true,
    mouseEnterControl: true
});
```